# g++ crash "pure virtual method called" instead of compilation error

Tags: c++, g++

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

class C
{
public:
    C(const A &a) : m_a(a) {}
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "in" << std::endl;
        m_a.foo(); //pure virtual method called terminate called without an active exception
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    const A &m_a;
};

int main()
{
    C c({});
    c.bar();
}
```

results in:

```
$ g++ virtual_crash.cpp
$ ./a.out 
in
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**My question is why this works on gcc?**

In `C c({});` construct abstract A (gdb traced). Explicit create of this object obviously falls in error. VS2017 fails for the same reason..

Comment: Which version of `g++`? Looks like a bug. `gcc` 8.1 gives compilation error. 7.3 - 7.5 actually compiles and runs without error. Older versions compile and give the same runtime error as you got.

Comment: Doesn't compile with `g++ 9.2.1` -- `"error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘A’"`.

Comment: Tried this on godbolt, and it looks like g++ 7.5 incorrectly compiles this with no diagnostics, but g++ 8.1 correctly complains that `A` is abstract.

Comment: $ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Comment: So it is a bug? thanks for confirmation..

Comment: Yes, the program is invalid, so silently succeeding is a bug. Possibly another version of https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83796

Comment: BTW, you also have dangling reference ^_^.

Comment: Yep, I know it was just to reproduce <no error> ;P